# returning data efficiently in loop with java script

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I recently fall in a loop pit when i tried to return data from a multi loop statement.

I am creating profile filtering system which after fetch people. It will filter the friends of the user.

```
 class UserFriend {

   analyseUserFriends(people, userfriends){
    people.forEach(person => {
        this.userfriends.forEach(friend => {
            if(person._id.toString() == friend._id.toString()){
                person.relationship = 0
            }else{
               person.relationship = 1;
             }
            return friend;//After loging friend the object of relationship is part of the member
        });
         return person;//After loging person the object of relationship is not part of the member
     });
  }
}
```

The data are from Mongo and it similar to this

```
     userfriends:[ 
    {friend: mongoId},
    {friend: mongoId},
    {friend: mongoId},
    {friend: mongoId},
];
people: [
    {_id: mongoId}, 
    {_id: mongoId}, 
    {_id: mongoId}, 
    {_id: mongoId},
    {_id: mongoId}, 
    {_id: mongoId}, 
    {_id: mongoId}, 
    {_id: mongoId}
];
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can not return any value from `forEach` use `map`,`filter` like functions

Comment: I would use userfriends.map(friends => { console.log(friends.friend) }) // mongoId

Comment: just as a note: your access to friend id doesn't correspond to your structure example (`friend._id` while i see no `_id` property in `userfriends`)

Answer (score 1):

As @Leafyshark mentioned in his comment, this is a usecase for the `map` method. Combining with the `find` method, you should be able to achieve this:

```
function analyseUserFriends (people, userFriends) {
    return people.map(person => {
        person.relationship = userFriends.find(x => x.friend.toString() === person._id.toString()) ? 1 : 0
        return person
    })
}
```